# Convert list elements with same values, to a one element with value

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

The title is dumb as i am with this one :)
I dont know is this even possible but i have to ask.. I am using ng-repeat with JSON in Angularjs and what i get is a list with these values..

```
 <ul>
     <li class="name">Nokia</li>
     <li class="name">Nokia</li>
     <li class="name">Nokia</li>
     <li class="name">ZTE</li>
     <li class="name">ZTE</li>
     <li class="name">Samsung</li>
     <li class="name">Samsung</li>
     <li class="name">ZTE</li>
</ul>
```

So from this list i want to make something like this

```
<ul>
 <li class="name">Nokia</li>
 <li class="name">ZTE</li>
 <li class="name">Samsung</li>
</ul>
```

Now i dont have idea, i've tried something with jQuery but with no success... My question is, is this even possible, and if it is, any suggestions?

OK, so you people are asking to see my JSON, but @nnnnnn has already solved my problem..
This is only the part of the JSON i've been working with... You are free to say if my structure is bad ;)

```
var store = [
                    {
                        "category": "mobile",
                        "description": "Mobile Phones",
                        "products" : 
                        [


                            {"manufacturer": "Nokia", "name":"Nokia 301", "price": 100, "quantity": 0, "img": "nokia301-front"},
                            {"manufacturer": "ZTE", "name":"ZTE FTV", "price": 300, "quantity": 0, "img": "zteftv-front"},
                            {"manufacturer": "ZTE", "name":"ZTE Blade 3", "price": 500, "quantity": 0, "img": "zteblade3-front"},
                            {"manufacturer": "Sony", "name":"Sony Xperia E", "price": 600, "quantity": 0, "img": "sonyxperiae-front"},
                            {"manufacturer": "Samsung", "name":"Samsung Galaxy Ace Plus", "price": 300, "quantity": 0, "img": "samsunggalaxyaceplus-front"},
                            {"manufacturer": "ZTE", "name":"ZTE Blade G", "price": 350, "quantity": 0, "img": "ztebladeg-front"},
                            {"manufacturer": "LG", "name":"LG Optimus L7 II", "price": 600, "quantity": 0, "img": "lgoptimusl7ii-front"},
                            {"manufacturer": "HTC", "name":"HTC Desire X", "price": 500, "quantity": 0, "img": "htcdesirex-front"},
                            {"manufacturer": "Nokia", "name":"Nokia Lumia 620", "price": 500, "quantity": 0, "img": "nokialumia620-front"}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "laptop",
                        "description": "Laptops",
                        "products" : 
                            [
                                {"name":"Asus X55A", "price": 400, "quantity": 0, "img": "asusx55a-front"},
                                {"name":"Samsung Series 9", "price": 500, "quantity": 0, "img": "samsungseries9-front"}
                            ]
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "tablets",
                        "description": "Tablet Devices",
                        "products" : 
                        [
                            {"name":"Prestigio Touch", "price": 270, "quantity": 0, "img": "prestigiotouch-front"},
                            {"name":"Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0", "price": 400, "quantity": 0, "img": "samsunggalaxytab270-front"},
                            {"name":"Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1", "price": 430, "quantity": 0, "img": "samsunggalaxynote101-front"}
                        ]
                    }
                ];
```

Comment: Well depends how you generate the first list. If there are duplicates in the JSON then you can just iterate over it and make a new array that only stores unique names. You should provide all the relevant code.

Comment: Of course it's possible. You can either process the data to remove duplicates before creating the html elements, or create the html elements and then remove the duplicates. (As an unrelated aside, if _every_ li element has the same class it would be neater to add the class to the containing ul element instead.)

Comment: @nnnnnn: Well removing HTML when you are binding to it with AngularJS in the first place is weird. He should filter the data if he just wants a different representation of the underlying model.

Answer (score 1):

A pure and stupid jQuery solution:

```
var names = [];
$("ul li").each(function(){
    if($.inArray($(this).text(), names) != -1){
        $(this).remove();
    }else{
        names.push($(this).text());
    }
});
```

[Try it in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyUWg/)

You would probably be better off making the list unique in the backend, but that depends on how the data is created.

Answer (score 1):

If it were my code I would remove the duplicates from the data before creating any html elements. However, since you have not shown any JavaScript or the JSON structure all I can give you is a way to remove the duplicates from the html:

```
var names = {};
$("ul li").filter(function() {
    var name = $(this).text();
    if (name in names)
        return true;
    names[name] = true;
    return false;
}).remove();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/C88Uj/

If you're not sure how the jQuery functions I've used work, you know [where to look](http://api.jquery.com/).

Comment: I actually like the functional aspect of this one better than mine :-)

Comment: This is just what i was searching for :) I'll edit the question so you good people can see my JSON...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the unique filter provided by Angular-UI

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | unique:attribute">{{ item.attribute }}</li>
</ul>
```

http://angular-ui.github.io/